# Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable such that $f'(x)>f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ and $f(0)=1$, then $f(1)$ lies in which interval?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, rolles-theorem

> Let $f:\mathbb  R\to \mathbb  R$ be differentiable function such that  $f'(x)>f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb  R$ and $f(0)=1$, then $f(1)$ lies in which one of the intervals ?
>
> a)$(0,e^{-1})$
>
> b)$(e^{-1},\sqrt{e})$
>
> c) $(\sqrt{e},e)$
>
> d)$(e,\infty)$

This is how I tried this question:

let $f(x)= 2e^{x}-1, $ so $f(0)=1$

$f'(x)=2e^{x} >f(x) \forall \; x\in R$

so $f$ satisfies the given conditions,

$f(1)=2e-1>e$ so d) should be correct. Is this correct? How can I solve this without using a particular example?

Comment: Consider $g(t) = e^{-t} f(t)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor does your function satisfies$ f'(x)>f(x)$ at $x=0$

Comment: You're correct and i think the particular example is a better method for a quick answer. But have you considered what I asked you to do

Comment: @Abhay I think he means "Take a function $f$ satisfying $f'(x)>f(x)$. Then consider the function $g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$. What can you say about this function?"

Comment: @Arthur thanks, I wasn't aware of the ambiguity

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$. Then $g'(x)=e^{-x} (f'(x)-f(x)) >0$. This  makes $g$ increasing . Hence $g(1) >g(0)$ which gives $f(1) >e$. Hence d) is true. This automatically rules out the other options.